# MySQL -- 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread --

Tags: mysql, macos, debugging, macos-monterey

Version of MySQL: 8.0.32-macos13-x86_64

Version of Mac:  MacOS Monterey Version 12.6

MySQL website says that the new MySQL Workbench version works for macOS Monterey. I don't know what is happening.

I just imported a csv file to my schema. Everytime I query I get the following error:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [10465]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.32.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-01-19 03:17:44.9915 -0600
OS Version:            macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D7CADE79-6CFA-56C5-76E6-E8F6163FEF5C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4EE1EC0E-2FA3-4AA7-82E1-2C43785F0D44

Time Awake Since Boot: 90000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       10320 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [10465]

Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81ddc5e9b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: From the csv import, what is the name of the table created?  Please post TEXT results from your MySQL Command prompt for A) SHOW CREATE TABLE your-table-name; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "your-table-name"; and C) query you are using, please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is on side of MySQL Workbench application for Mac. Latest versions are not working correctly. I had the same crashes with simple select operation on 8.0.32. Try to use 8.0.29 version which is working perfectly.
You can download mysql-workbench-community-8.0.29-macos-x86_64.dmg on official website (click on tab archive and select version in the list).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to make this answer "more clear". I've proposed the solution that helped me to solve exact the same issue.